# In Django, how to remove language prefix conditionally after internationalization ? Media file src problem

Tags: django, static, internationalization, django-urls

In a django project, after a query I'm sending image srcs to a JS file that will then create popovers dynamically on my home page using these image srcs and some text data.

ex : `popover_photo.src = 'media/' + popover_data['photo__src']`

After adding internationalization to my project, all my pages are prefixed by language code like 'en' or 'es', the problem being that my image srcs also gets prefixed by a language code automatically. Instead of having 'media/my-example-image.png' I will get 'en/my-example-image.png' and the image file won't be found.

So, is there a way to remove language prefix conditionally in django on a particular endpoint OR more specifically, is there a way to exclude my call to my media folder from having a language prefix ?

Thanks in advance if any dev is willing to share a workaround about this !

My main urls.py currently looks like this (I'm still in development, but I'm going to use AWS S3 in a bit to stock my images, might the same problem occur?):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('__debug__/', include('debug_toolbar.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += urlpatterns + i18n_patterns(
    path('rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls')),
    path('', include('core.example_app.urls', namespace='example_app')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: You would do the addition before adding the i18 patterns. flow: define urlpatterns, append media patterns, THEN you would add static patterns.

Comment: I tried it before, but it doesn't work, it stills prepend a language suffix before my media location.

Comment: are you sure the file exists? when using localization; django tends to append the prefix after a page 404s.

Comment: My bad, the problem was actually a missing slash : instead of `popover_photo.src = 'media/' + popover_data['photo__src']` I should have written `popover_photo.src = '/media/' + popover_data['photo__src']`